# Función de "entrar" en "No dejaron entrar a los niños"

Tags: gramática, sintaxis

En la siguiente frase:

> No dejaron entrar a los niños.

...no consigo ver cuál es la función de entrar.

Al principio creía que se trataba de una perífrasis verbal (dejar entrar). Sin embargo, "dejar + infinitivo" no aparece en ninguna lista de perífrasis verbales que haya consultado. Lo que es más, en dos PDFs ([este](https://ciervalengua.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/perifrasis-verbales.pdf) y [este](http://www.iesseneca.net/iesseneca/IMG/pdf/Perifrasis_verbales-_clasificacion_y_ejercicios_con_autocorreccion-2.pdf)), la frase aparece explícitamente como un ejemplo de lo que *no* es una perífrasis.

En ambos PDFs, se explica que "a los niños" es el CD ("No *los* dejaron entrar"), pero ninguno especifica la función de "entrar". Evidentemente no es un CI. Podría ser otro CD, pero, por una parte, no es sustituible por lo, la, los, las (*No lo dejaron a los niños) ni convertible en sujeto en una pasiva (**Entrar no fue dejado a los niños); y por otra, yo al menos jamás he visto ninguna frase con *dos* complementos directos.

- Así que, ¿qué es entrar?

Paralelamente, esta pregunta me ha hecho preguntarme si es siquiera posible que una frase tenga más de un complemento directo:

- ¿Existe alguna frase que pueda tener dos o más complementos directos?

Comment: Dependiendo del hablante *a los niños* puede ser u objeto directo u objeto indirecto. Solo pasa con los verbos *hacer* y *dejar*: los demás verbos de influencia solo admiten a la persona como indirecto salvo que el verbo obligue una preposición de régimen, en cuyo caso es directo.  En ambos casos, *entrar* es un verbo subordinado no conjugado (cf. el infinitivo personal del portugués) con el sujeto implícito de *los niños*

Comment: Se consideran correctos tanto «yo les dejé/hice hablar a ellas» como «yo las dejé/hice hablar en voz alta» según el DPD, pero habría diferencia en la interpretación de la función de *ellas* (obviamente, CI en la primera oración, CD en la segunda).  Según la *Gramática* ha habido bastante debate sobre el infinitivo, pero dice que hoy se considera generalmente como un complemento predicativo.  Puedes leer sobre el debate en §26.9-10

Comment: @guifa Ya veo que en general no está tan definido como otros conceptos gramaticales. Lo que se dice sobre complemento predicativo tiene sentido, pero no me termina de convencer. Si posteas el comentario como una respuesta la puedo dar por buena.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El verbo principal "**dejar**" es aquí sinónimo de "**permitir**". Y este funciona como un "**verbo de influencia**".

Eso se comprueba en la sustitución del verbo subordinado en infinitivo ("*entrar*") por *"que"+subjuntivo* : "*No dejaron (a los niños) que entraran*"

El complemento ("los niños") funciona como objeto indirecto, pero suele sustituirse por el pronombre correspondiente al objeto directo ("los" en lugar de "les") en algunos casos. Aquí, ambas formas "No les dejaron entrar" o "No los dejaron entrar" suenan correctas, con leve preferencia por la segunda.

Del [diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=DRC2Ny6YAD6yEoSWaX):

> Los llamados «verbos de influencia» —los que expresan acciones que
>   tienen como objetivo influir en una persona para que realice una
>   determinada acción, como *autorizar, ordenar, invitar (‘animar’)*,
>   *permitir, exhortar*, etc.—, forman parte de la siguiente estructura:
>   «**verbo de influencia + complemento de persona + verbo subordinado, en
>   infinitivo o precedido de que, o un nombre de acción**»: *Le ordené
>   ejecutar la sentencia / Le ordené que ejecutara la sentencia / Le
>   ordené la ejecución de la sentencia*.
>
> El complemento de persona es
>   indirecto con los verbos permitir, prohibir, proponer, impedir, mandar
>   y ordenar: «Esa experiencia le permitió vivir a su manera» (Alberto
>   Eternidad [Cuba 1992]); «Le prohibió salir de la capital hasta nueva
>   orden» (Tribuna [Hond.] 18.6.97); «Le propuso hacer un viaje a la
>   costa» (Landero Juegos [Esp. 1989]); «La penumbra le impide ver con
>   claridad» (Schmidhuber Ventana [Méx. 1985]); «Quién le manda soltar
>   pendejadas» (Medina Cosas [Méx. 1990]); «La Policía les ordenó que no
>   lo hicieran» (Clarín [Arg.] 18.4.97). Por el contrario, el complemento
>   de persona es directo con los verbos de influencia que llevan, además,
>   un complemento de régimen, esto es, un complemento precedido de
>   preposición, como obligar a, invitar a, convencer de, incitar a,
>   animar a, forzar a, autorizar a, etc.: «Una barrera los obligó a
>   desviarse» (Fuentes Cristóbal [Méx. 1987]); «La convenció de que
>   vendiera un anillo de brillantes» (Allende Casa [Chile 1982]); «Ella
>   lo incitó a seguirla» (Martini Fantasma [Arg. 1986]).
>
> Los verbos **hacer** y *dejar*, cuando tienen sentido causativo, esto es,
>   cuando significan, respectivamente, ‘*obligar*’ y ‘*permitir*’, siguen la
>   misma estructura que los verbos de influencia: «*verbo causativo +
>   complemento de persona + verbo subordinado*». Tanto *hacer* como *dejar*
>   **tienden a construirse con complemento directo si el verbo subordinado**
>   **es intransitivo**: «Él la hizo bajar a su estudio y le mostró el cuadro»
>   (Aguilera Caricia [Méx. 1983]); «Lo dejé hablar» (Azuela Tamaño [Méx.
>   1973]); y tienden a construirse con complemento indirecto cuando el
>   segundo verbo es transitivo: «Alguien lo ayudó a incorporarse, lo
>   estimuló y hasta le hizo tomar café» (JmnzEmán Tramas [Ven. 1991]);
>   «El alcaide de la cárcel le dejaba tocar el banjo todas las mañanas»
>   (Cela Cristo [Esp. 1988]).

Comment: Supongo que lo que me molesta de hacer/dejar es que no tienen una función sintáctica clara. A todos los verbos subordinados del 2° párrafo se les puede atribuir una función (CD o C de Rég.), pero nada se dice de los que siguen a "hacer" y "dejar". Tampoco se pueden sustituir por *eso*: la dejó pasar = la dejó eso (?), lo cual es posible con los demás: le permitió pasar = le permitió eso, se lo permitió. Ello indica que son distintos de alguna manera. Según la RAE podrían ser un C predicativo, pero no atribuyen ninguna cualidad al sujeto. ¿Serán simplemente una laguna en la gramática española?